# single scroll bar for multiple lists boxes. flash CS6

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

I have been having issues getting a single scrollbar to work with multiple list boxes. I wanted something similar to how Excel does it visually
i ended up using a slider bar and using the value of this bar to change the selectedIndex of the list box. This did not work however.

This is the code i was using:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

slider1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,scrolling);
function scrolling(evt:MouseEvent)
{
trace(slider1.value);
slider1.maximum=InstanceName_1.length;
InstanceName_1.selectedIndex=slider1.value;
InstanceName_2.selectedIndex=slider1.value;
InstanceName_3.selectedIndex=slider1.value;
InstanceName_4.selectedIndex=slider1.value;
}
```

with InstanceName_n being the different lists i used.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Just a thought - isn't it easier to put all lists into one HBox (or HGroup) so they are all side to side and then just use the scroller of that HBox (or wrap the HGroup into a scroller)?

Answer (score 0):

I think the listener function is wrong, try using this

```
 slider1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,scrolling);
```

this might help , because this is when mouse is down and is moving , normally used for drag/drop times , still you can try it , it will work